# How to validate a formcontrol with prepopulated data in Angular 5?

Tags: angular5

I have a form-group. In the form-group, i have a form-array. I have initialized the array with items created from data in the data model with the method as described in angular's documentation on reactive forms, under the section  Initialize the secretLairs FormArray. The problem is i need to perform validation.required for each form control in the array. However, since the form-controls already hold values, i do not know how to perform validation.required. The documentation did not go further on how to validate formcontrols in a formarray that are prepopulated.

Here are my source codes:

.html

```
    <!-- list of Questions -->
   <div formArrayName="questions">
     <!-- <div *ngFor="let que of Questions; let k=index"> -->
      <div *ngFor="let question of Ques ; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" >

        <!-- The repeated questions template -->
      <h4>{{question.ques}}</h4>
      <div style="margin-left: 1em;">
        <!-- <div class="form-group">
         <label class="center-block">
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="ques" >
         </label>
            </div> -->

         <div class="form-group radio" *ngFor="let choice of 
         question.choices; let j = index">

         <input type="radio"  formControlName="choices"
         class="custom-control-input" [value]="choice.choiceText">
         <label>{{choice.choiceText}}</label>
         </div> 

         <br>
         <!-- End of the repeated questions template -->

         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" 
         [disabled]="!CheckListForm.valid">Submit</button>
         </form>
```

.ts

```
  export class CheckListFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  CheckListForm: FormGroup;

  Ques: Questions[];

  employmenttype = ['Permanent', 'contractor'];



   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
               private checklistservice: ChecklistService) { 
      this.CreateForm();

                                                            }

     ngOnInit() {
    this.checklistservice.getQuestions(1).subscribe(res =>{ this.Ques =res;
    this.setquestions(this.Ques)
                 }); 


    this.CheckListForm.get('EmploymentType').valueChanges.subscribe(

    (EmploymentType: string) => {
      if (EmploymentType === 'Permanent') {
        this.CheckListForm.get('HRMS').setValidators([Validators.required]);

     this.CheckListForm.get('CompanyName')
      .setValidators([Validators.nullValidator]);
      } else if (EmploymentType === 'contractor') {

        this.CheckListForm.get('CompanyName').
        setValidators([Validators.required]);

        this.CheckListForm.get('HRMS').
        setValidators([Validators.nullValidator]);
                                                 }

         this.CheckListForm.get('HRMS').updateValueAndValidity();
         this.CheckListForm.get('CompanyName').updateValueAndValidity();
                                                               }
                                                                   )
                                                                        }




 CreateForm() {
 this.CheckListForm = this.fb.group({

 name: ['', Validators.required],
 EmploymentType: ['', Validators.required],
 HRMS: [''],
 CompanyName:[''],
 questions: this.fb.array([]) 
  })
  }


get questions(): FormArray {
return this.CheckListForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
                           }

setquestions(questions: Questions[]) {  
const QuestionsFGs = questions.map(questions => this.fb.group(questions));
const QuestionsFormArray = this.fb.array(QuestionsFGs);
this.CheckListForm.setControl('questions', QuestionsFormArray);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, as there is no response from anyone, I will post the answer which i have painstakingly solved.

You cannot validate form-controls through the method i have performed(see my codes). The reason is because the form-controls already hold data and is not empty in the first place. Hence, validation.required will not work.

A solution will be to instead push empty form-controls for each item in the array of the data model.

Validation.required will then work for this case.